# Ubuntu20.04 : How to give non root user access to systemctl

Tags: ubuntu, authentication

- The ubuntu version is 20.04
- I am running a http service on port 6000.
- I have created the service and as a user root i can run the service successfully
- I have created a account `svc_auto_bm` and wanted this user to have the capability to start service `http.server.service`

I did configure the file

```
root@LB1EDGRSISNBX02:/etc/systemd/system# cat http.server.service
[Unit]
Description = Job that runs simple http server daemon

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/svc_auto_bm/projects/lab_automation_bot/output
User=svc_auto_bm
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -m http.server 6000
ExecStop=/bin/kill `/bin/ps aux | /bin/grep http.server | /bin/grep -v grep | /usr/bin/awk '{ print $2 }'`
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=wmulti-user.target

root@LB1EDGRSISNBX02:/etc# lsb_release 0a
Usage: lsb_release [options]

lsb_release: error: No arguments are permitted
root@LB1EDGRSISNBX02:/etc# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
root@LB1EDGRSISNBX02:/etc#
```

There are two problems:

1. When I ran as non root user `svc_auto_bm` it list user for providing password and in that list `svc_auto_bm` is missing
2. It should have accepted the command automatically because i have configured the following for polkit in `cd /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d`:

   ```
   root@LB1EDGRSISNBX02:/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d# cat service-auth.pkla
   [Allow svc_auto_bm to start/stop/restart services]
   Identity=unix-group:svc_auto_bm
   Action=org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units
   ResultActive=yes
   root@LB1EDGRSISNBX02:/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d#
   ```

I have also configured the rules in  /etc/polkit-1/rules.d

```
cd /etc/polkit-1/rules.d
root@LB1EDGRSISNBX02:/etc/polkit-1/rules.d# cat service-auth.rules
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
        subject.isInGroup("svc_auto_bm")) {
        if (action.lookup("unit") == "http.server.service") {
            var verb = action.lookup("verb");
            if (verb == "start" || verb == "stop" || verb == "restart") {
                return polkit.Result.YES;
            }
        }
    }
});
root@LB1EDGRSISNBX02:/etc/polkit-1/rules.d# cat http.server.rules
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
        subject.isInGroup("svc_auto_bm")) {
        if (action.lookup("unit") == "http.server.service") {
            var verb = action.lookup("verb");
            if (verb == "start" || verb == "stop" || verb == "restart") {
                return polkit.Result.YES;
            }
        }
    }
});
root@LB1EDGRSISNBX02:/etc/polkit-1/rules.d# cat svc_auth_bm.rules
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
        subject.isInGroup("svc_auto_bm")) {
        if (action.lookup("unit") == "http.server.service") {
            var verb = action.lookup("verb");
            if (verb == "start" || verb == "stop" || verb == "restart") {
                return polkit.Result.YES;
            }
        }
    }
});
root@LB1EDGRSISNBX02:/etc/polkit-1/rules.d#
```

Comment: Rather than a `ps | grep` construct use the dedicated `pgrep` command to identify a process by name or simply use `pkill` when you want to terminate a particular process by name rather than PID.

Comment: Is the user `svc_auto_bm` in the group `svc_auto_bm`?

Comment: Check this link it should fix your problem. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192706/how-could-we-allow-non-root-users-to-control-a-systemd-service